# Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.zipkin.java:zipkin-autoconfigure-ui:jar is missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, zipkin

I am developing Microservices specifically `"zipkin-service"`. I have taken a reference from  link: https://www.baeldung.com/tracing-services-with-zipkin.

Could anyone please guide what's the issue ?

When I added below dependencies, then I get the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Error:

> Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.zipkin.java:zipkin-autoconfigure-ui:jar is missing.

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**ZipkinServiceApplication.java**

```
@EnableZipkinServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ZipkinServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this under your  section at the end of your pom.xml. you may need to add for all the dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
  <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
  <version>what-ever-version-number</version></dependency>
```

Comment: Ideally it should be fetched by Parent pom, but looks like its not happening, hence added latest versions too. @EnableZipkinServer is from import zipkin2.server.internal.EnableZipkinServer; now

Comment: correct, by looking at your pom, your parent is spring-boot-starter, so you need to add it in your pom.